# Papers from thesis - short term postdoc?

Tags: funding, job-search, postdocs

I am a PhD candidate in Physics who handed in his thesis a few months ago and will defend soon. I am based in Sweden and I am now applying for postdocs outside Europe in different fields and working (mostly "translating" materials which was already in the thesis) on three papers from my thesis. At the moment I have no papers published, but my thesis work is quite good.

Do you think it could be possible (and a good idea) to find a short-term (1-2 months) grant, so that I can work full time and finish the papers before starting a postdoc (my supervisor has no funding for that)? Otherwise things will just take longer, I think. Do you have any suggestion regarding where to look? Thanks!

Comment: Finding a grant might be as difficult as finding a job, so I'd opt for finding a job. You can finish papers once you have a job.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not in Physics, my experience and knowledge (Comp Sci) would suggest that:

- Finding such a grant would generally be difficult.
- Your best bet would have been some kind of late-PhD-research-assistant/short-term-PostDoc employment with your PhD advisor or at your lab; if that's still an option, try it;
- Maybe it's possible to get a part-time short-term teaching/teaching assistance position instead of a proper research grant; it "eats away" some of your paper-writing time, but it might be better than no job at all